# Разделить текст на предложения

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно разделить текст на предложения.
Использовал регулярное выражение "`\\.|!|?`" 
Но это не совсем правильно, потому что в таком случае разделяются на разные предложения "и т.д, т.п. А.С.Пушкик"

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.|!|?");
    separeteText = pattern.split(temp);
```

Comment: Учитывая ещё конструкции наподобие

    «О Боже! — вскричала королева, — я беременна, и неизвестно, от кого!»

задача кажется нереальной без привлечения искусственного интеллекта.

Comment: Реальна. Можно проверять начинается ли следующее слово буквой в верхнем регистре, если нет, тогда делать конкатенацию строк. Но это нужно перебирать массив. Что очень долго если текст большой. Я хочу найти решение регулярными выражениями.

Comment: А как насчёт `зам. Генерального Секретаря`? `Слово имеет т. Сухов`? `3 р. 62 коп.`?

Comment: Поддерживаю @VladD, задача не реальна без искусственного интеллекта.  
Здесь можете посмотреть решение, которое не пропустит итд итп и АС.Пушкин, правда оно на питоне, но портировать никто не запрещает:  
http://hashcode.ru/questions/197142/

Comment: Можно вместо "." искать " .". Не идеал, но с т.д. - подобными справится

Comment: @danpetruk: но не с более правильным «и т. д.».

Comment: @VladD Кстати моё решение не учитывает ещё одну вещь: "и т.д. и т.п." разобьёт на 2 предложения